# Hurwitz matrix and positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, hurwitz-matrices

Hurwitz Matrices require that for a polynomial to have all **negative** real part roots then the determinant of the principle minors must be positive.

I know that if we have a positive definite matrix then all the real parts of the eigenvalues are **positive**, and also that the determinant of the principle minors are positive.

> My question is: How are the two related?

As the characteristic polynomial to the Hurwitz matrix will have **positive** real parts to the solutions. So what is the relation (or formation of Hurwitz matrices) between the polynomial of **negative** real part roots and the Hurwitz matrix, which will have a characteristic polynomial of positive real part roots.